# Linking APEX accounts to schemas?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is it possible to link apex accounts to multiple schemas or they can only link to the individual schema?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Logon as Admin, go to

- manage workspaces
- manage workspace to schema assignment
- click "Add schema" (upper right corner)
- follow the wizard (it's easy; choose a schema and add it to desired workspace)